# Trigger a keyboard shortcut through mouse click event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on( 'keypress', 'body', function( e ){
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if( code = 110 ) {
            console.log( 'Successfully triggered ALT+N' );
        }
    });

    $(document).on( 'click', '#copy', function(  ){
        var e = $.Event('keypress');
        e.which = 110; // Character 'A'
        console.log( e );
        $('body').trigger(e);
    });

});
```

The above piece of code successfully triggers the keyboard shortcut **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>** on my document.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keyboard shortcut does a particular action on my web page such as copying content of all form fields through Firefox plugin.

When `#copy` button is clicked through mouse, the keyboard action triggered through jQuery but the corresponding action is not taking place.

But when i press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> from keyboard directly the action occurs.

Is it possible to trigger a keyboard shortcut through mouse click event?

Comment: There is some information here http://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm

Comment: the code works for me!!! the console shows the desired result when clicking the #copy button!!!.can you elaborate the issue???