# Trigger keyboard shortcut via Javascript mouse button click event

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I need the ability for users on an internal intranet site to click a button and open their file search, which is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> keyboard command. Ideally I need them to click a button to open a particular local file folder, but I know this isn't possible on Chrome without an extension.

How can I trigger the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> command via JavaScript?

I found the following:

> [Trigger a keyboard shortcut through mouse click event using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650342/trigger-a-keyboard-shortcut-through-mouse-click-event-using-jquery)

But I don't understand where the alt key command is being instigated?

**Edit:

Which part of the following calls the alt key and the n key? I see the e.which is 110, but all I can find of the keyCode lists is that 110 cooresponds to the decimal point key. (Such as [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/), [here](http://keycode.info/), etc)

I'm using `jQuery(document)` due to Wordpress restriction.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(document).on( 'keypress', 'body', function( e ){
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if( code = 110 ) {
            console.log( 'Successfully triggered ALT+N' );
        }
    });

    $(document).on( 'click', '#copy', function(  ){
        var e = $.Event('keypress');
        e.which = 110; // Character 'A'
        console.log( e );
        $('body').trigger(e);
    });

});
```

Comment: The code `110` corresponds to the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

Comment: My understanding was that `110` corresponds to the N key?

Comment: You can't trigger a keyboard shortcut triggered by a browser. If you want a file upload, use [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Comment: I don't want to upload a file, it lives in our internal file system which defets the purpose. I just want users to click a button that will open the file search on their windows computer that you can do with the ctrl + o keyboard command.